# Display text on webpage from list depending on date

Tags: php, wordpress, spreadsheet

I'm not professional developer, but I help to manage the IT for a group of churches in the UK. I thought this might be the place to ask for help.

They have a website, which runs wordpress. They also have a monthly prayer diary. There is a list, and each day, members pray for something or someone specific.

I was wondering if there was a way of displaying the day's prayer using PHP/HTML, on the site, from a list of prayers that is located on the server. For example, on 1st July, it might be 'We pray for the local schools', so somewhere on the site, on the 1st July would be the text 'Today we pray for the local schools'. This would automatically change to something like 'we pray for our local firefighters' on the 2nd of July, depending on what is on the list.

This would preferably be done by easily uploading a csv file(?) to wordpress/the web server, and the site would automatically find and display the prayer associated with today's date (server-side time) from the file???

I'm running wordpress on Windows IIS, with PHP of course.

I would be really grateful if someone could help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the skills to write a wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'quote of the day' plugin. There are a number of them available, you just need to find one that allows you to upload the content.

Here's a search to start you off: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=wordpress+plugin+quote+of+the+day

The Flexi Quote Rotator on this page looks promising: https://hostingreviewbox.com/10-awesome-free-quote-of-the-day-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I wanted, but I didn't know what to look for. Thanks for your help!